# document.execCommand not holding click event

Tags: jquery

I am trying to bold text with a click on a button. I created it in JS Fiddle and it works fine. However, the issue is when I put the script on the web page. It performs the action but it does not hold the click event

https://jsfiddle.net/lvwiseguy/v7jm03zu/7/

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#BoldText').click(function () {
                document.execCommand('bold');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        #editable_textarea {
          width: 100%;
          height: 150px;
          border: 1px solid blue;
        }

        button {
          font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <button id="BoldText">B</button>
        <div id='editable_textarea' contenteditable="true">
          Select text and click the button to make it bold...
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: You have `id="form1"` there, does it mean you also have `id="form2"` with exactly the SAME child elements inside it?

Comment: @AlonEitan no form1 is the default id you an aspx page is created.